# Express regex route not working

Tags: regex, node.js, express

I'm working on a pagination feature for the homepage's blogpost.
I've created a regex for it that I have tested and works, but if I redirect to '/' because the page number is larger than the amount of posts I have, I'm getting a `Cannot GET '/'` error...

UPDATE: It ONLY errors when redirected. When accessed normally, it works like a charm

This is my routing code:

```
server.get(/^(\/)$|^(\/[0-9]*)$/g, co.wrap(function *(req, res, next) {
    try {
        console.log('hi');

        const postRepo = repo_storage.get('post');
        const skipper = req.originalUrl.substr(1);
        const amount = 15;

        const post_opts = {
            skip: 0,
            limit: 15
        };

        post_opts.skip = skipper !== '' ? (skipper - 1) * amount : 0;

        const posts = yield postRepo.find({page: false, live: true}, post_opts);
        // posts is an array of posts gotten from Mongo

        if (posts.length === 0) {
            console.log('redirecting...');
            res.redirect('/');
            return;
        }

        res.locals.body = {
            posts
        };
        res.locals.page = 'home';
        next();
        return;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('route / error', e);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    }
}));
```

Comment: Express used `path-to-regexp` [https://github.com/component/path-to-regexp] module to route. See examples there.

Comment: Updated the post: It only errors when being redirected, when I normally access it, it works 100% like intended.

Comment: I think that `posts.length` is `undefined` and `if (posts.length === 0)` skipped on redirect. Try change condition to `if (!post.length)`.

Comment: It doesn't enter the route, the first `hi` doesn't show up in my terminal either

Comment: I do not know why, if someone could clarify, please do, but I solved it after reconstructing the regex to `/\/[0-9]*$/` and it now works